# No known class method for selector 'simplePingWithHostName: SimplePing iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I am having trouble using SimplePing I receive the following error when copying over the `SimplePing.h` and `SimplePing.m` files I downloaded from [Apple SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

`No known class method for selector 'simplePingWithHostName:'`

From this method in my `SimplePingClient.m` class:

```
-(void)pingHostname:(NSString*)hostName andResultCallBlock:(void(^)(NSString* latency))result
{
    _resultCallback = result;
    _pingClient = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:hostName];  // No known class method for selector 'simplePingWithHostName:'
    _pingClient.delegate = self;
    [_pingClient start];
}
```

I'm calling this method from another file like this, where there are no errors:

```
-(void)testNetworkLatency {
    [SimplePingClient pingHostname:@"www.apple.com"
    andResultCallback:^(NSString *latency) {

        NSLog(@"your latency is: %@", latency ? latency : @"unknown");

    }];
}
```

I tried changing `[SimplePing simplePingWithHostName...` in `SimplePingClient.m` to variations of pingHostname, initWithHostName, sendPingWithData but nothing has worked so far. Did something change with SimplePing or am I going wrong somewhere?

[Link to a screenshot of all the methods available in SimplePing.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK0Fb.jpg) as you can see, there is no `simplePingWithHostName`

Comment: it must be in the framework headerfiles , did you import the headerfiles in the other class you are trying to implement it on?

Comment: "I'm calling this method from another file like this" No. You are calling `pingHostname:` not `simplePingWithHostName`. Also it's not clear. What is `SimplePingClient`? Is there an extension of the method (Category in Objective-C) ? Your code isn't found in that file.

Answer (score 0):

it is wise to read the class definitions before coping and pasting but once done you can take them for granted because thats what they are for. You will have much more fun when following them. But keep on trying as this is a classic beginner mistake in objC when taking over language concepts from elsewhere but not objC.

You will want to set a global variable to keep your simple ping object around.

```
@implementation YourClass {
    SimplePing *_pingClient;
}
```

alternative in

```
@interface YourClass : YourInheritingClass <NeverGiveUpProtocol>

@property (nonatomic) SimplePing *pingClient;  

@end
```

and in your implementation method allocation and initiation of your ping object is done like

```
_pingClient = [[SimplePing alloc] initWithHostName:hostName];
```

Also you will have to be careful with the definition of block parameters that are doing nothing and are set up to accept NSStrings. You can read about block definitions in methods here
https://riptutorial.com/objective-c/example/1761/blocks-as-method-parameters

You can tell the compiler that you don't need a specific parameter like so ..
if you cant avoid to define it.

```
-(void)yourmethod:(NSString*)hostname resultBlock:(void(^)())result {
#pragma unused(result)
    // your stuff
}
```

Hint: *SimplePing* and *SimplePingClient* seem to be total different classes where the last one contains *pingHostname:* as external method. (Means you can call it without explicit initiation.) Ending up in a method definition like..
`+(void)pingHostname:(NSString *)hostname;` which is why you would need to call it directly on the ClassName.
The Apple example does not contain a class named `SimplePingClient`.
Thats probably result of your creative process. Yeah maybe you want to ping from the app you create to the same app on a different device - well, why not. Cheers